# Generate euclidean distance matrix from two dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, random, networkx, shuffle

I have two dictionaries that represents Areas and Police_Dept. My goal should be to calculate the euclidean distance among each areas/Police_Dept. Starting from these two dictionaries with `networkx`, I created a graph as shown in the code below:

[image: This is the first dict representing areas]

[image: This is the second dict representing Police_Dept]

Now I generate a graph with `networkx`:

```
G = nx.Graph()

#nodes with f=1 refers to area
i = 1
for k in data1:
    G.add_node(i, areaName=str(data0[k][0]), numberOfCrimes=str(data0[k][1]),
               D=random.randint(10,20), f=1)
    i += 1

#nodes with f=0 refers to Police_dept
for k in data0:
    G.add_node(i, numberOfD=str(data0[k][1]), f=0)
    i += 1

#I simply calculate random distance but this is not the case
distances = {}
for i in G.nodes():
    if G.node[i]['f'] == 1:
        for j in G.nodes():
            if G.node[j]['f'] == 0:
                distances[i,j] = random.randint(i,j)
```

Is there a solution to substitute my `distances` with the euclidean distance well calculate for each pair of area-->Police_Dept node using random order (position) of areas and departments like in the real life?

Comment: To calculate the 2D Euclidean distance between the two things (an area and a Police Dept), you need to know the location of each, which in this case is likely be be something like longitude and latitude (pretending the Earth is flat). Is that information available, and if so, where is it (since it does not appear to be in your data)?

Comment: @martineau unfortunately I don't have it, but we can make some assumptions and calculate it randomly  if needed. We only have the data i printed on the question.

Comment: Well, I suppose if you generated two random coordinates for each location, you can use the [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) function to calculate the distance between them (using `x2-x1`, `y2-y1` as arguments to it). The range of random values for `x` and `y` doesn't matter much mathematically, except if you want meaningful looking values (like kilometers or miles) think of them as map coordinates measured in those terms relative to some common origin.

Comment: The idea is to take a fixed number of Districts that can cover the max number of Areas, I still have a constraints that will check if the distance **d** is acceptable or not regarding to another parameter that is **D** so I think I have to choose their with a sense. By the way, pratically  should I add  add the coordinates while creating the nodes(passing it as argument of the G.add_node)?

Comment: It's not clear to me what **`D`** is supposed to represent, just generate a random `(x, y)` coordinate for each positions with reasonable values relative to whatever units are being used (e.g. kilometers or miles). Add them when creating the nodes and then compute the distance between between them—using `hypot()`—when adding values to the `distances` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.. so **D** represent the max acceptable distance in which an area node should be connected to a district node(e.g I want that no more than 10km of distance are acceptable ) and for this I set my **D** variable. so.. in your opinion what should be reasonable values to use? I want to manage Km so in which range shall i choose my (x,y) ?

Comment: You'll want to pick `x` and `y` coordinate values so that `hypot(x2-x1, y2-y1)` returns something less than **`D`**. This means their actual values aren't important, just the _differences_ between them (or more precisely the square root of the sum of their differences squared) which is what using `hypot()` will effectively be calculating in that case.

Comment: I want also the case in which i exceed my **D** to show that the formulation works properly. So let me check if I understand. when I create the nodes associated to both dictionaries in the function i will add two variables **x** and **y** (which values are to define) . After i will iterate on those nodes and i will do the following: 
'distances[i,j] = hypot((x[i]-x[j]),(y[i]-y[j]))'
Should work?

Comment: The `distances[i,j] = hypot((x[i]-x[j]),(y[i]-y[j]))` looks correct. As for **`D`**, for given ranges of possible `x` and `y` values, the maximum distance will be when the one between the (0, 0) and (maximum x, maximum y) locations. If you pick **`D`** values less than that, it will increase the likelihood that pairs of the randomly generated values in those ranges will exceed it.

Comment: As shown in the code if "D=random.randint(10,20)"  so I have to choose 
"x=random.randint(0,20)" AND "y=random.randint(0,20)" ?